# Compound predicate of "They would make me feel alive"

Tags: sentence-construction

> They would make me feel alive

Is there a compound predicate "would make feel"? "They" is a subject, and "me" is a object (Who?),and "alive" is an adverbial (How?)?

Comment: I'd say ***alive*** there is an ***adjective*** - describing what ***I*** would feel like, not an adverbial describing ***how*** they would cause me to feel that way.